# Drag and drop some files/folders into ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd2qE.png)

I have a application file manager, it contains listview1 and listview2. I want to drag a file or folder from the listview1 to listview2 and contrary but it can't work.
I have the following code:

```
       private void listView_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
       {
          listView.DoDragDrop(listView.SelectedItems[0].Tag.ToString(), DragDropEffects.Copy);
       }

    private void listView_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView lv = (ListView)sender;

        // Returns the address of the mouse pointer on the ListView Control.
        Point cp = lv.PointToClient(new Point(e.X, e.Y));

        // Get the item at the specified position of the cursor.
        ListViewItem dragToItem = lv.GetItemAt(cp.X, cp.Y);

        if (dragToItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string dest = dragToItem.Tag.ToString();
        DirectoryInfo dri = new DirectoryInfo(dest);

        // Declare the string variable containing the path containing the destination file
        string dest1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(dest);

        string s = (string)(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(s);
        string fileName = "\\" + Path.GetFileName(s);


        // Drag and drop are a file
        if (dri.Attributes != FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            dest1 = dest1 + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(s);

            if (dir.Attributes == FileAttributes.Directory)
            {
                FileSystem.CopyDirectory(s, dest1, UIOption.AllDialogs);
            }
            else
            {
                FileSystem.CopyFile(s, dest1, UIOption.AllDialogs);
            }

            LoadListViewSubFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(dest1));
        }
        else
        {
            dest = dest + fileName;

            if (dir.Attributes == FileAttributes.Directory)
            {
                FileSystem.CopyDirectory(s, dest, UIOption.AllDialogs);
                LoadListViewSubFiles(dri.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                FileSystem.CopyFile(s, dest, UIOption.AllDialogs);
            }

        }
    }

    private void listView_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Any errors?  It doesn't look like you move the actual ListView item, but call this undocumented method: `LoadListViewSubFiles`

Comment: I can't drag and drop file/folder to listview. I try to but it still does't work. I have the following code for LoadListViewSubFiles.
https://pastebin.com/tmtXSsvd

Comment: Step through your `DragDrop` method with a debugger and determine where your code deviates from your expectations. Also why are you not simply calling `listView.DoDragDrop(listView.SelectedItems[0], DragDropEffects.Copy);` and inserting that item into the other list?